# Wordpress 3.5+, JavaScript, wp.media.editor.open

Tags: wordpress, editor, media

I'm developing a plugin for Wordpress, where I need to create a gallery with images.

In JavaScript I call Media editor to create a gallery, using this code: wp.media.editor.open(btn).

Editor opens with default "Insert Media" tab. I would like it to open from "Create Gallery" tab. Can you please advise, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this.

```
var gallerysc = "[gallery ids='123,12,10']";
wp.media
    .gallery
    .edit(gallerysc)
    .on('update', function(g, x) {

        console.log(g.models);
    });
```